# How to find location of an IP Address Without using APIs?

Tags: geolocation, ip

More of a theoretical question. Yes, I know those types of questions are frowned upon here. But suppose APIs like MaxMind GeoIP's didn't exist, and you wanted to build a service that translated IP addresses to the city it's in. What would you do? How would you go about solving that problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use the whois database to find out who the IP is allocated to.
2. Use DNS to do a reverse lookup on the IP address.
3. Use traceroute to guess the location based on the routers leading up to the host

As an example, lets look at stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12)

```
$ whois 64.34.119.12 | egrep "(OrgName)|(City)|(State)|(Country)"
OrgName:        Peer 1 Network Inc.
City:           New York
StateProv:      NY
Country:        US
```

whois shows us that they're probably in NY, NY.

```
$ host 64.34.119.12
12.119.34.64.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer stackoverflow.com.
```

Reverse DNS (PTR record) doesn't help here. However, a lot of ISPs do have region specific reverse DNS entries that can help with this process (especially for dynamically assigned hosts).  As an example:

```
$ host 24.25.195.1
1.195.25.24.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer sndgca-dns-cac-01.san.rr.com.
```

This host is obviously identified and located by it's PTR record: a Time Warner (Road Runner) caching DNS server in San Diego, CA.

Now, back to the stackoverflow.com locating process:

```
$ traceroute stackoverflow.com
traceroute to stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12), 64 hops max, 40 byte packets
ms
 (... removed the first few hops ...)
 8  ae-6-6.ebr1.Chicago1.Level3.net (4.69.140.189)  30.9 ms  28.855 ms  25.183 ms
 9  ae-2-2.ebr2.NewYork2.Level3.net (4.69.132.66)  54.373 ms  54.197 ms  48.171 ms
10  ae-6-6.ebr2.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.69.141.21)  48.250 ms  50.712 ms  51.293 ms
11  ae-62-62.csw1.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.69.148.34)  59.493 ms ae-82-82.csw3.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.69.148.42)  51.694 ms ae-62-62.csw1.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.69.148.34)  58.315 ms
12  ae-3-89.edge1.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.68.16.142)  51.529 ms ae-2-79.edge1.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.68.16.78)  50.77 ms ae-3-89.edge1.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.68.16.142)  50.567 ms
13  10ge-te-1-1.nyc-75bre-dis-2.peer1.net (216.187.115.77)  50.776 ms  51.193 ms  56.166 ms
14  gig2-0.nyc-gsr-b.peer1.net (216.187.123.5)  54.994 ms  58.813 ms  51.794 ms
15  gwny01.stackoverflow.com (64.34.41.58)  54.121 ms  52.65 ms  54.166 ms
16  * * *
(... remaining time outs removed ...)
```

The traceroute output confirms our suspicion that stackoverflow.com is hosted in NY, NY.

That's one way to tackle geolocation without an API.

Answer (score 1):

Im really guessing here but this may work.

IP ranges are assigned by [IANA](http://www.iana.org) to regional providers. There are five of them. In turn each regional provider assign IP ranges to end users and internet service provides.
If you can get/buy the information from the regional providers and their ISP clients you are in business.